# ABCMeta object argument after ** must be a mapping, not tuple

Tags: python, arduino

`arduino = serial.Serial(com, 115200, 0, **('timeout',))`

Error : TypeError: ABCMeta object argument after ** must be a mapping, not tuple

I'm starting a python project that communicates with the arduino by serial
the project is quite simple to make the mouse move using host shield together with arduino
but i get this error

Comment: `**` is syntax for `dict` unpacking. What would you expect it to do to a `tuple`?

Comment: what should i change?

Answer (score 0):

A group of keyword arguments needs to be supplied via a `dict` (or some other mapping type), not a `tuple`.

```
arduino = serial.Serial(com, 115200, 0, **{'timeout': 1})
```

or more simply,

```
arduino = serial.Serial(com, 115200, 0, timeout=1)
```

as generally you only use the `**` syntax when you have a dict-valued variable to unpack. For example,

```
kwargs = {'timeout': 1}
arduino = serial.Serial(com, 115200, 0, **kwargs)
```